# Cordova Embedded webview not responding navigator.camera is undefined

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, webview

I am trying to get my cordova webview to work with cordova 3.2 an use the phonegap Camera API to access the camera.

Reference: [Android WebViews](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews)

Here are some successful implementations of what I want to do, but these use [Phonegap 1.9](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/index.html), i want to use [Phonegap 3.2](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/index.html) (the latest one)

[Cordova WebView using Android](https://github.com/stevengill/CordovaActionView)

Also here's a [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQXHDIe7bVU)

With the code below I am able to make the cordova webview display my index.html page without any issues but when I to access the camera by clicking on "Capture Photo" in my HTML, cordova returns the following error message:

```
12-12 16:18:05.097: D/CordovaLog(26390): file:///android_asset/www_old/lefty.html: Line 71 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined

12-12 16:18:05.097: E/Web Console(26390): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL' of undefined:71
```

My files are as follows:

assets/www/index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        //alert(navigator.canera.toSource());
        //console.log(navigator.toSource());
        //alert( JSON.stringify(cordova)); 
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Java Code:

```
MainActivity.java

package co.canvo.app;


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.LOG;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {
    private boolean mAlternateTitle = false;
    private boolean bound;
    private boolean volumeupBound;
    private boolean volumedownBound;

    String TAG = "MainActivity-ActionBarTest";
    private CordovaPlugin activityResultCallback;
    private Object activityResultKeepRunning;
    private Object keepRunning;

    CordovaWebView mainView;
//  CordovaWebView lefty;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        //set the main veiw and its content
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainView = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        mainView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Called when a message is sent to plugin.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            The message id
     * @param data
     *            The message data
     * @return Object or null
     */
    public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
        LOG.d(TAG, "onMessage(" + id + "," + data + ")");
        if ("exit".equals(id)) {
            super.finish();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setActivityResultCallback(CordovaPlugin plugin) {
        this.activityResultCallback = plugin;
    }
    /**
     * Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished. When this activity exits,
     * your onActivityResult() method is called.
     *
     * @param command           The command object
     * @param intent            The intent to start
     * @param requestCode       The request code that is passed to callback to identify the activity
     */
    public void startActivityForResult(CordovaPlugin command, Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        this.activityResultCallback = command;
        this.activityResultKeepRunning = this.keepRunning;


    // If multitasking turned on, then disable it for activities that return results
    if (command != null) {
        this.keepRunning = false;
    }


    // Start activity
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);


    }   


    @Override
    /**
     * Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
     * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
     *
     * @param requestCode       The request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(),
     *                          allowing you to identify who this result came from.
     * @param resultCode        The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
     * @param data              An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
     */
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        CordovaPlugin callback = this.activityResultCallback;
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        }
    }



    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mainView.pluginManager != null) {
            mainView.pluginManager.onDestroy();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ExecutorService getThreadPool() {
        return this.getThreadPool();
    }





}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id = "@+id/mainView"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at


 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "3.2.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>


    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    -->

    <!-- This is required for native Android hooks -->
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
</feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: Any comments or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm beginning to worry.. :(

Comment: Does `DATA_URL` don't need to be initialized? I found `Camera.DestinationType = { DATA_URL : 0, FILE_URI : 1};` from this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!! Had forgotten to add:

```
Config.init(this);
```

in my Java code just before:

```
mainView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

All set, thanks JunM for trying but that wasn't the issue